# N static fields vs single static instance

Tags: c#, static

I was looking into singleton format, it is very similar to something I used before.

My question is, is there any difference memory and/or performance wise between these two approaches, is the second option faster, enough to cover up for its usage being larger to write and read?

Here is an example code:

**Method 1**

```
public static class TheSomething {
    public static String Title;
    public static String Description;
    public static String HowIsIt;
    public static int TimesSeenCount;
    public static List<Long> PeopleWhoSawIt;
    public static List<Session> PeopleSeeingIt;

    // now some math mumbo jumbo just to increase the memsize of this:
    public static double posX;
    public static double posY
    public static double posZ;
    public static double velX;
    public static double velY;
    public static double velZ;
    public static double accX;
    public static double accY;
    public static double accZ;
    public static double rotX;
    public static double rotY;
    public static double rotZ;
    public static double rotVelX;
    public static double rotVelY;
    public static double rotVelZ;
    public static double rotAccX;
    public static double rotAccY;
    public static double rotAccZ;
    public static List<Vertex> Geometry;
}
```

To be used with:

```
++TheSomething.PeopleWhoSawIt;
```

**Method 2**

```
public static class TheSomething {
    private static TheSomething _instance;
    public static Instance { 
        get {
            if(_instance == null)
                _instance = new TheSomething();
        } private set {
            _instance = value;
        }
    }
    private TheSomething() {}
    public String Title;
    public String Description;
    public String HowIsIt;
    public int TimesSeenCount;
    public List<Long> PeopleWhoSawIt;
    public List<Session> PeopleSeeingIt;

    // now some math mumbo jumbo just to increase the memsize of this:
    public double posX;
    public double posY
    public double posZ;
    public double velX;
    public double velY;
    public double velZ;
    public double accX;
    public double accY;
    public double accZ;
    public double rotX;
    public double rotY;
    public double rotZ;
    public double rotVelX;
    public double rotVelY;
    public double rotVelZ;
    public double rotAccX;
    public double rotAccY;
    public double rotAccZ;
    public List<Vertex> Geometry;
}
```

To be used with:

```
++TheSomething.Instance.PeopleWhoSawIt;
```

Comment: This is very complex subject and my answer would be a repetition of what people smarter than me have already said. Please read this article from SO champion Jon Skeet  [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

Comment: "is it faster" is something that can be answered only by _you_, by running a valid performance test under realistic conditions similar to your actual scenario. Your example doesn't make much sense (incrementing an instance of `List<T>`?), but if anything I would expect the static class to be faster (perhaps by some inconsequential or even immeasurable amount) than the singleton. At best, the question here is too broad, and at worst doesn't include enough information for anyone to answer it for your specific scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise neither option will provide you with a substantial improvement. They fall into the range of micro-optimizations that won't make much (if any) difference on a real-world scenario.

From a design perspective, both options are quite bad, with the first one being particularly evil. In general, the singleton pattern is frown upon as developers tend to abuse and overlook various side effects associated with it like holding on to memory or resources or lack of multithreading support.

If you still require a single instance for that class, try looking into using a Dependency Injection container rather than designing the class itself to be a singleton.

Comment: Yeah I do eventually need some classes to "just perform stuff" or "just store this single piece of globally used information", like System.Convert for example, but I may also need to store some values in these classes so both of those examples seem fit for this purpose. Assuming there is no performance difference then I'd assume the first model (often even used by the framework itself) would seem to fit better. And agreed I can't see a good reason to use the singleton. Thanks for the info, looking forward to dependency injection pattern.